# Can't install ubuntu in HP elite book 840 g3

Tags: 22.04, ssd

I want to ask that I'm trying to install ubuntu in my laptop Hp elite book 840 g3 but when i try to install it show an error of sgx disable i tried to much on BIOS to set this problem but I can't find this sgx in any option tell me how can i resolve this issue because i need to install ubuntu so help me for this
Thanks!

Comment: when you can't find sgx in bios sittinges try minimal ubuntu installation

Answer (score 2):

EliteBook 840 G3 comes with 5 different versions intel 6th generation processors and all of them support intel SGX with ME. But this feature is dependent on both processor and the manufactures bios.

If your bios is out of date then update it from: https://support.hp.com/sg-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-840-g3-notebook-pc/7815294

After that if you still don't find the SGX option then I guess it is for some reason disabled by the manufacturer.